# How to list own Active Directory group memberships with Python LDAP3?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group, ldap3

I log in to Active Directory, then I want to list my own group memberships with Python ldap3 library.

```
server = Server('server.company.local', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user="company\\user", password="password", authentication=NTLM, auto_bind=True)
print(conn.extend.standard.who_am_i())
```

This code only shows user name (like `whoami` cmd command), but i want to list my groups (like `whoami /groups` command).
Unfortunately I dont have the rights to make different searches on the Domain controller, thats why (perhaps) the following code returns empty string:

```
conn.search("dc=name,dc=company,dc=local","(&(sAMAccountName={}))".format("company\\myusername")
            ,attributes=['memberOf'])
```

How can i list my own group membership, like `whoami /groups` does?

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory generally allows all authenticated users to read a lot of attributes, including memberOf. Check the number of records returned for your search. I expect you are finding zero records with that search. sAMAccountName values do not generally contain the "company\" component but are just "myusername".

Comment: I tried the same with sAMAccountName=myusername too, but i still get zero records.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the search base in my search: I replaced `"dc=name,dc=company,dc=local"` to `"dc=company,dc=local"` It works fine.